# Change hyperlink text in cell using string function(s)

Tags: excel, vba

Given a cell containing a hyperlink, I want to change the appearing text using string functions such as Mid, but still maintain the hyperlink address and functionality. What can I do? Thanks.

**Examples:**

Example 1:

Cell contains this hyperlinke:     15 Mary Street

Required output is this hyperlink: Mary Stree - I want the link to work if I click on "Mary Street" just as it did when I click on "15 Mary Street".

Example 2:

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to do, it's a little unclear. Can you post some sample data/formulas, and what the expected outcome is?  What's the `Hyperlink()`  formula you're using, and what do you want it to do?  FYI you can do something like `=Hyperlink("http://www.google.com/"&A1,"Link"&B1)`  Per your edit: So, a hyperlink *links* to that address, or the "link text" is `15 Mary Street` and you just want the link text?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I have updated the question. I am not using any functions as of now the hyperlink is data with no functions applied, I want to be able to manipulate the text that appears to the user.

Comment: So do you just want the text that's following the street/house number?

Comment: Yes, but I want also to maintain the hyper link functionality. So that if I click on Mary Street, I go to the same destination.

Comment: And to be clear - you are not using `Hyperlink()` - you've copy/pasted the link to Excel, and it shows that text with an "embedded" link?  What does the formula bar show when you click into a hyperlinked cell?

Comment: Yes the hyperlink is copied from a web site. The formula bar shows the exact same text that is displayed in the cell. I can edit it manually, but I have so many!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126366/discussion-between-brucewayne-and-nochance).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will keep your link, or break it. If it breaks it, let me know.

```
Sub test()
     removeLeadingNumbers Range("A1:A10")
End Sub


Sub removeLeadingNumbers(myRng As Range)
Dim cel As Range, chr As String
Dim i As Long, k As Long

For Each cel In myRng
    If Not IsEmpty(cel) Then
    i = Len(cel)
    For i = 1 To Len(cel)
        If IsNumeric(cel.Characters(i, 1).Text) Then
            k = k + 1
        Else
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
    Debug.Print "remove the first " & k & " letters"
    cel.Value = Trim(Right(cel.Value, Len(cel.Value) - k))
    End If
Next cel
End Sub
```

Comment: This works, may be we need to initialize K for each iteration and remove i=len(cell), but the idea is valid. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the displayed text to remove a leading number followed by a space, then try:

```
Sub DumpTheNumbers()
    Dim h As Hyperlink, txt As String

    For Each h In ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks
        txt = h.TextToDisplay
        If InStr(txt, " ") <> 0 Then
            arr = Split(txt, " ")
            If IsNumeric(arr(0)) Then
                arr(0) = " "
                h.TextToDisplay = Trim(Join(arr, " "))
            End If
        End If
    Next h
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately, some of the links I have contain internal blanks.